# The action tag is not working in live server vs code

Tags: javascript, html, forms, action

I am trying to run html file using the form in the vs code. But the live server is not allowing it to run. I tried it with normal chrome to run the file both files are running in normal chrome but not on the live server also it is navigation to welcome file when submit is clicked. Don't know what's wrong with the vs code.
Code below:
welcome.html

```
<head>
    
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome To The Prajakta's LOGIN</h1>
</body>
</html>
Validateform
<html>
<head>
   <script>
       function val()
       {
          
           var name=document.getElementById("txtname").value;
           var pass=document.getElementById("txtpass").value;
          /* if(name==null||name=="")
           {
               alert("Name cannot be blank")
               return false;
           }
           else if(pass.length<6)
           {
               alert("Minimum length of password should be more than 6");
               return false;
           }*/
       }
       </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="welcome.html" onsubmit="val()">
        Name : <input type="text" id="txtname" name="txtname"><br>
        Password : <input type="password" id="txtpass" name="txtpass"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Click here">
        </form>
</body>
</html>

I tried it with normal chrome to run file both files are running in normal chrome but not in live server.
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are running on the live server, your form is sending a `POST` request to the `/welcome.html` file which is no handing that request that is why you are receiving `405 Method Not Allowed`

There should be something at the back that handles the `POST` method, called as server-side or back-end technologies. Each server-side language (PHP, Python, Ruby, Java, C#, etc.) has its own mechanism of handling form data.

Example welcome.php

```
<html>
<body>
  <h1>Welcome To The Prajakta's LOGIN</h1>
  Hi <?php echo $_POST["txtname"]; ?>
</body>
</html>
```